# Execute a method of different signature in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

From the below code, I want to execute `foo3` after `foo2` is complete in `foo1`. The method signature of `foo1` cannot be changed. One way would be to move `foo3` into `foo2`, but that would be breaking separation of concerns.

```
@Override
CompletableFuture<Integer> foo1(String str) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> foo2(str));
}

Integer foo2(String str) {
    return 0;
}

void foo3(String str) {
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Comment: make your lambda call foo3 after foo2.  `{ int res = foo2(str); foo3(str);  return res; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `foo3` call should be part of `foo1`, then this is one way:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> foo1(String str) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> foo2(str))
            .thenApply(foo2Result -> {
                        foo3(str);
                        return foo2Result;
                    }
            );
}
```

Or if you want to call it, in places where `foo1` is called:

```
foo1(str).thenApply(result -> {
            foo3(str);
            return result;
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to call the `foo3` after `foo2` and return `foo2` output, then you can do like this:

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                Integer r = foo2(str);
                foo3("testing");
                return r;
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
foo1(str).thenRun(() -> foo3(str);
```

since you don't seem interested in `foo1`'s result.

Comment: Do you mean `return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> foo2(str)).thenRun(() -> foo3(str));`? This doesn't work because it returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see, but I want `foo3` to be called within `foo1`, not outside.